# ios simulator can't scroll to bottom

Tags: xcode, ios

I am trying to change a setting ios simulator but I scroll to bottom to get to this setting: Here is as much as I can see:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With trackpad, scroll with 3 fingers, like you're doing it with Safari or Preview, but with 3 fingers on simulator. I you don't have trackpad, click and drag, as if the mouse pointer was your finger .

Comment: scroll with 3 doesnt work, just click and drag